# How to enable a dropdown list of predetermined items to add to a custom control in SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

The `DialogPane` has this implementation in `SceneBuilder`:

You can add to the Pane a list of buttons.

[image]

I am looking to do this for my custom control in scenebuilder. I could not find anything obvious inside the constructor for `DialogPane` that would make this work.

Is doing this a possibility?

```
private final ObservableList<ButtonType> buttons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public DialogPane() {
    getStyleClass().add("dialog-pane");

    headerTextPanel = new GridPane();
    getChildren().add(headerTextPanel);

    graphicContainer = new StackPane();

    contentLabel = createContentLabel("");
    getChildren().add(contentLabel);

    buttonBar = createButtonBar();
    if (buttonBar != null) {
        getChildren().add(buttonBar);
    }
    buttons.addListener((ListChangeListener<ButtonType>) c -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                for (ButtonType cmd : c.getRemoved()) {
                    buttonNodes.remove(cmd);
                }
            }
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                for (ButtonType cmd : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    if (! buttonNodes.containsKey(cmd)) {
                        buttonNodes.put(cmd, createButton(cmd));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting... The place to look to figure out how this works is probably the source code for [Scene Builder](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/src). You need to figure out if it just treats this property in `DialogPane` as a special case (in which you are probably out of luck), or if it looks for something specific (a read only property which has a type that has some constants defined of the same type, or something...).

Answer (score 0):

You should try clicking in the library-panel on the settings-icon in the top-right corner, then click on Costum Library Folder -> Reveal In Explorer.

For more information, see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/library-panel.htm).

Comment: This control is not custom.